# How to disable Nginx double gzip encoding when fastcgi backend occasionally serves gzipped with content-encoding?

Tags: php, nginx, gzip, fastcgi, content-encoding

Is there any clever way to trick nginx to stop gzip if the backend already has set the "content-encoding" header?

Nginx is configured to gzip the output from the php fastcgi backend.

This works great in 99% of the cases.

Except on rare occasion php will send a raw gzipped file and attach a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header.

Nginx unfortunately will go right ahead and try to gzip that content a second time.

The produces a double `content-encoding: gzip` `content-encoding: gzip` header and double-encoded gzipped body.

Most modern browsers can handle this, Firefox, Chrome.

IE8 cannot, Safari mobile cannot, old Safari 5 for Windows cannot - instead they will show garbled gzipped content because it merges the content-encoding headers and only decodes the gzipped body once.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I have the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: I had this issue also. Solved it by adding the Vary-header to my application code: `header('Vary: Accept-Encoding');`

Answer (score 4):

Somewhere in nginx.conf where it applies (there should be a fastcgi_params file somewhere) :

```
fastcgi_param  HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING      "";
```

This will disable the encoding from the backend.

I hope that still Nginx will serve encoded content after this. (I am not sure)