# Nginx sub_filter doesn't works with fastcgi_pass

Tags: nginx

For some reason `sub_filter` doesn't works with `fastcgi_pass` which is pointing to CGI script in perl in my case.

If I try to apply sub_filter to static HTML all works fine and it swaps hrefs as expected.

Here's the config:

```
location /proxy/
    sub_filter '<a href="http://'  '<a href="//';
    sub_filter_once off;

    fastcgi_pass             proxy:8002;
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(/proxy)(/?.*)$;
    fastcgi_param            SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param            PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 14400;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43264821/2234964) answer that problem might be with compression that my backend script does. In case of `proxy_pass` they use `proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";` to turn off compression.

In my case with `fastcgi_pass` this directive helped me (found related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34407420/2234964)):

```
fastcgi_param HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING "";
```